# Doing a diff between two keystore files

Tags: linux, openssl, java, bash, perl

I have a keystore file with certificates and I want to compare if the second keystore has exactly the same contents as the first one.
One approach would be to extract the certificates using `keytool` and the compare the certificates digest e.g.

```
keytool -exportcert -rfc -alias  user_cert -file cert_user1.pem -keystore  keystore1.jks -storepass 1234 -v 

keytool -exportcert -rfc -alias  user_cert -file cert_user2.pem -keystore  keystore2.jks -storepass 1234 -v

diff <(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in cert_user1.pem | openssl md5) <(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in cert_user2.pem | openssl md5)
```

Another approach is do compare the digest of the keystore files directly

```
diff <(openssl md5 keystore1.jks)<(openssl md5 keystore2.jks)
```

The issue I can think of with these approaches is that they both report a difference if the password of one of the keystore changes. The first approach also "breaks" if the `alias` in the keystore changes.

So I think `diff <(openssl md5 keystore1.jks)<(openssl md5 keystore2.jks)` is more reliable but I am not sure if using `md5` is a good idea here.

Is there another way?

Comment: I have used the tags `bash` and `perl` because whatever approach I will do in a bash/perl script

Answer (score 2):

`md5` is a worst idea. If a single bit changes, the hash will change.

You need to export the contents of each keystore and compare the relevant fields of them, not every single bit of information.For instance, if you don't care about the creation time, you don't need to compare them.

So create a script in `perl` or `bash` that opens the keystores, exports only the relevant fields, and compare them. You could, for instance, output the relevant data to a file, and use `diff` on them.

Comment: `If a single bit changes, the hash will change.` why is this bad though?

Comment: To give you a bit of a context, they two keystores would contain the same certificates with different expiration dates. I.e. I am trying to see if there is a diff between the keystores which would mean the second would contain the newer issued certificate. If there is a diff I would compare the expiration date. If there is no diff I would not do anything

Comment: So it would be easier to just extract and compare the expiration date. You don't need to test if they are equal and later compare the expiration dates.

Comment: I thought it could be a minor optimization.

Comment: You would read 2 files once to determine if they are the same, and read both them again when they differ, so 4 times if they are different and 2 if they are the same. If you just compare them, you read 2 files only once.